# CIMD2 Protocol API for ASP.NET C#

Tags: asp.net

I am developing an application that needs to communicate with a Mobile Operator Messaging Center via CIMD2 protocol. I am trying to find something that has already been implemented, but the only solutions I can find cost around 1000$ US. Can anyone suggest anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that there is a Linux based program http://www.kannel.org/, and people run it on a linux box and communicate with it from .NET on a Windows box. (might run the linux box on a virtual machine).

You might also want to port the code to C# (there is a JAVA port out there).